# How to JSON.parse an Array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, type-conversion

I am being passed a JSON.stringified Array of arrays in a var called request.

```
alert(request);
```

gives this message:

```
"[[\"0\",\"MahaShivRatri\"],[\"0\",\"A Night with the Divine\"],[\"0\",\"Attend In-Person\"],[\"0\",\"11 March 2021\"],[\"0\",\"6 PM to 6 AM IST\"],[\"0\",\"Attend Mahashivratri celebrations with Sadhguru in the presence of Adiyogi at the Isha Yoga Center\"],............
```

now, I try this:

```
var arr = JSON.parse(request);
alert(arr);
```

It gives the below message which looks like an Array of arrays:

```
[["0","MahaShivRatri"],["0","A Night with the Divine"],["0","Attend In-Person"],["0","11 March 2021"],["0","6 PM to 6 AM IST"],["0","Attend Mahashivratri celebrations with Sadhguru in the presence of Adiyogi at the Isha Yoga Center"],.........
```

but when I try to alert a particular element of this Array:

```
alert(arr[0][1]);
```

It gives *undefined* in the alert box.

How to get an Array of arrays from a JSON.stringified Array of arrays?
(Essentially I want to manipulate the DOM while I loop through arr.)

Thank you.

---

### Edits

**1. The original full stringified request is this :**

`console.log(request);`

**logs this**

`"[[\"0\",\"MahaShivRatri\"],[\"0\",\"A Night with the Divine\"],[\"0\",\"Attend In-Person\"],[\"0\",\"11 March 2021\"],[\"0\",\"6 PM to 6 AM IST\"],[\"0\",\"Attend Mahashivratri celebrations with Sadhguru in the presence of Adiyogi at the Isha Yoga Center\"],[\"0\",\"Limited Seats Available\"],[\"0\",\"<CTA> - BOOK YOUR SEAT NOW \"],[\"0\",\"In-person attendance is open only for people in India due to COVID protocols.\"],[\"1\",\"SECTION HEADING- 2021 Celebrations Highlights\"],[\"1\",\"Mahashivratri is an exuberant nightlong festival with explosive meditations by Sadhguru and spectacular musical performances by renowned artists. Join the celebrations and experience the grace of Adiyogi.\"],[\"1\",\"\"],[\"1\",\"  <text limit - 110 chars>   Powerful Satsang with Sadhguru   Explosive guided meditations with Sadhguru   Nightlong special musical performances by eminent artists   Adiyogi Divya Darshanam, a spectacular light & sound show depicting the origin of Yoga   Devi Maha Arati, a grand procession of the Linga Bhairavi Utsava Murti   Cultural performances by Sounds Of Isha   Traditional and Martial Arts performances by Isha Samskriti students\"],[\"1\",\"  \"],[\"1\",\"  \"],[\"2\",\"SEATING LAYOUT\"],[\"2\",\"- Seating is open only for people in India. - Booking is open on a first-come-first-serve basis - COVID precautions are mandatory (See FAQ)\"],[\"2\",\"HOW TO REACH THE VENUE\"],[\"2\",\"Isha Yoga Center,\"],[\"2\",\"Velliangiri Foothills,\"],[\"2\",\"Ishana Vihar Post,\"],[\"2\",\"Coimbatore 641 114, India\"],[\"2\",\"Contact\"],[\"2\",\"83000 82000\"],[\"2\",\"info@mahashivarathri.org\"],[\"3\",\"Additional Information\"],[\"3\",\"Your contribution towards the event will help us make the possibilities of this night available to millions around the world.\"],[\"3\",\"Limited Seats Available\"],[\"3\",\"<CTA> - BOOK YOUR SEAT NOW \"],[\"3\",\"\"],[\"3\",\"\"],[\"3\",\"Invite Your Family and Friends\"],[\"4\",\"\"],[\"4\",\" Frequently Asked Questions\"],[\"4\",\"In-Person Attendance FAQ\"],[\"4\",\"What precautions should attendees take in light of COVID-19?\"],[\"4\",\"Since the guidelines are regularly evolving, the currently applicable guidelines issued by the government and local health authorities will be followed. Participants must abide by these guidelines:\"],[\"4\",\"• It is mandatory to wear a mask at all times.\"],[\"4\",\"• You must adhere to all social distancing protocols and COVID-19 safety guidelines laid down during the event.\"],[\"4\",\"• Get a COVID test done within a 96-hour period before your arrival at the Isha Yoga Center.\"],[\"4\",\"• We recommend that you practice Simha Kriya regularly and consume Nilavembu Kashayam daily, leading up to the event.\"],[\"4\",\"Can I register offline?\"],[\"4\",\"Yes. For more information, call 83000 82000.\"],[\"4\",\"What documents will I need when I arrive at the Isha Yoga Center?\"],[\"4\",\"Please bring:\"],[\"4\",\"The same valid government-issued photo identification that you used to register for MahashivratriPrintout of the E-pass that was sent to you via email\"],[\"4\",\"What time do I need to reach the Isha Yoga Center for the event?\"],[\"4\",\"Check-in counters will be open only from 10 AM to 3 PM on the day of the event for those who have pre-registered. We request you to plan your travel accordingly since we will not be able to accommodate check-ins outside these timings.\"],[\"4\",\"Please stay back for the event until 6 AM on 12 March. Due to security reasons, participants will not be allowed to leave the venue once checked-in.\"],[\"4\",\"Restroom facilities are available at the venue.\"],[\"4\",\"I don’t know Tamil. Can I still attend this program?\"],[\"4\",\"Yes, Mahashivratri will be conducted in English with Tamil translation. Live translation for online participants will be available in 7 Indian languages (Tamil, Hindi, Marathi, Bangla, Telugu, Kannada, and Malayalam) and 5 global languages (Russian, Mandarin, Spanish, French, and Portuguese).\"],[\"4\",\"I have difficulty sitting on the floor.\"],[\"4\",\"Chairs will be provided for the entire duration of the event.\"],[\"4\",\"Will accommodation be provided during the program?\"],[\"4\",\"No. Accommodation will not be provided for Mahashivratri participants.\"],[\"4\",\"Can I bring family members/guests with me?\"],[\"4\",\"No, entry is limited to registered participants only.\"],[\"4\",\"Can I bring my children? What is the minimum age required to participate in the program?\"],[\"4\",\"We do not have facilities or resources to take care of children and/or minors during the event. We request you to arrange guardianship at home for them while you are here. Alternatively, you could choose to stay in Coimbatore and come to Mahashivratri with your family. In such a case, please register for seating passes for your family as well.\"],[\"4\",\"The minimum age for participants is 10 years. \"],[\"4\",\"What kind of food can I bring to the event?\"],[\"4\",\"Maha Annadanam – an offering of food – will be provided to everyone attending the event. If you have to carry your own food due to dietary restrictions, you can carry wholesome vegetarian meals.\"],[\"4\",\"Can I bring my vehicle? Is parking available?\"],[\"4\",\"Limited parking will be available. Parking is at the owner’s risk and no liability will be taken by event organizers.\"],[\"4\",\"Can I register for Mahashivratri on arrival at the venue?\"],[\"4\",\"No. Spot registrations will not be available. We recommend that you register for Mahashivratri at least 15 days before the event. \"],[\"4\",\"How do I know if my registration is complete?\"],[\"4\",\"Once you register for Mahashivratri, you will receive an E-receipt and a confirmation email with your registration number. Closer to the event, an E-pass will be sent to you via email.\"],[\"4\",\"I have not attended Inner Engineering. Can I take part in Mahashivratri?\"],[\"4\",\"Yes, the Isha Mahashivratri event is open to everyone.\"],[\"5\",\"\"],[\"6\",\"NA\"]]"`

**2. When I parse it and then log it:**

`var arr = JSON.parse(request);`
`console.log(arr);`

**This gets logged:**

`[["0","MahaShivRatri"],["0","A Night with the Divine"],["0","Attend In-Person"],["0","11 March 2021"],["0","6 PM to 6 AM IST"],["0","Attend Mahashivratri celebrations with Sadhguru in the presence of Adiyogi at the Isha Yoga Center"],["0","Limited Seats Available"],["0","<CTA> - BOOK YOUR SEAT NOW "],["0","In-person attendance is open only for people in India due to COVID protocols."],["1","SECTION HEADING- 2021 Celebrations Highlights"],["1","Mahashivratri is an exuberant nightlong festival with explosive meditations by Sadhguru and spectacular musical performances by renowned artists. Join the celebrations and experience the grace of Adiyogi."],["1",""],["1","  <text limit - 110 chars>   Powerful Satsang with Sadhguru   Explosive guided meditations with Sadhguru   Nightlong special musical performances by eminent artists   Adiyogi Divya Darshanam, a spectacular light & sound show depicting the origin of Yoga   Devi Maha Arati, a grand procession of the Linga Bhairavi Utsava Murti   Cultural performances by Sounds Of Isha   Traditional and Martial Arts performances by Isha Samskriti students"],["1","  "],["1","  "],["2","SEATING LAYOUT"],["2","- Seating is open only for people in India. - Booking is open on a first-come-first-serve basis - COVID precautions are mandatory (See FAQ)"],["2","HOW TO REACH THE VENUE"],["2","Isha Yoga Center,"],["2","Velliangiri Foothills,"],["2","Ishana Vihar Post,"],["2","Coimbatore 641 114, India"],["2","Contact"],["2","83000 82000"],["2","info@mahashivarathri.org"],["3","Additional Information"],["3","Your contribution towards the event will help us make the possibilities of this night available to millions around the world."],["3","Limited Seats Available"],["3","<CTA> - BOOK YOUR SEAT NOW "],["3",""],["3",""],["3","Invite Your Family and Friends"],["4",""],["4"," Frequently Asked Questions"],["4","In-Person Attendance FAQ"],["4","What precautions should attendees take in light of COVID-19?"],["4","Since the guidelines are regularly evolving, the currently applicable guidelines issued by the government and local health authorities will be followed. Participants must abide by these guidelines:"],["4","• It is mandatory to wear a mask at all times."],["4","• You must adhere to all social distancing protocols and COVID-19 safety guidelines laid down during the event."],["4","• Get a COVID test done within a 96-hour period before your arrival at the Isha Yoga Center."],["4","• We recommend that you practice Simha Kriya regularly and consume Nilavembu Kashayam daily, leading up to the event."],["4","Can I register offline?"],["4","Yes. For more information, call 83000 82000."],["4","What documents will I need when I arrive at the Isha Yoga Center?"],["4","Please bring:"],["4","The same valid government-issued photo identification that you used to register for MahashivratriPrintout of the E-pass that was sent to you via email"],["4","What time do I need to reach the Isha Yoga Center for the event?"],["4","Check-in counters will be open only from 10 AM to 3 PM on the day of the event for those who have pre-registered. We request you to plan your travel accordingly since we will not be able to accommodate check-ins outside these timings."],["4","Please stay back for the event until 6 AM on 12 March. Due to security reasons, participants will not be allowed to leave the venue once checked-in."],["4","Restroom facilities are available at the venue."],["4","I don’t know Tamil. Can I still attend this program?"],["4","Yes, Mahashivratri will be conducted in English with Tamil translation. Live translation for online participants will be available in 7 Indian languages (Tamil, Hindi, Marathi, Bangla, Telugu, Kannada, and Malayalam) and 5 global languages (Russian, Mandarin, Spanish, French, and Portuguese)."],["4","I have difficulty sitting on the floor."],["4","Chairs will be provided for the entire duration of the event."],["4","Will accommodation be provided during the program?"],["4","No. Accommodation will not be provided for Mahashivratri participants."],["4","Can I bring family members/guests with me?"],["4","No, entry is limited to registered participants only."],["4","Can I bring my children? What is the minimum age required to participate in the program?"],["4","We do not have facilities or resources to take care of children and/or minors during the event. We request you to arrange guardianship at home for them while you are here. Alternatively, you could choose to stay in Coimbatore and come to Mahashivratri with your family. In such a case, please register for seating passes for your family as well."],["4","The minimum age for participants is 10 years. "],["4","What kind of food can I bring to the event?"],["4","Maha Annadanam – an offering of food – will be provided to everyone attending the event. If you have to carry your own food due to dietary restrictions, you can carry wholesome vegetarian meals."],["4","Can I bring my vehicle? Is parking available?"],["4","Limited parking will be available. Parking is at the owner’s risk and no liability will be taken by event organizers."],["4","Can I register for Mahashivratri on arrival at the venue?"],["4","No. Spot registrations will not be available. We recommend that you register for Mahashivratri at least 15 days before the event. "],["4","How do I know if my registration is complete?"],["4","Once you register for Mahashivratri, you will receive an E-receipt and a confirmation email with your registration number. Closer to the event, an E-pass will be sent to you via email."],["4","I have not attended Inner Engineering. Can I take part in Mahashivratri?"],["4","Yes, the Isha Mahashivratri event is open to everyone."],["5",""],["6","NA"]]`

**3. finally**

`console.log(arr[0]);`

**logs just this:**

`[`

Comment: Using the exact input string above, I can `JSON.parse(s)[0][1]` and get a value of `"MahaShivRatri"`

Comment: You are missing context of your code. Is there an async call to an API or database? If so, you only are certain to "have" the data after an `await` or inside of a `.then` (if you are trying to log the data outside of that scope).

Comment: @crashmstr thanks. No, there is no async call, but there was some other issue somewhere else with my code. In my code, I was calling JSON.stringify on my Array twice, but calling JSON.parse on it just once. I removed one call to JSON.stringify and the variable is now getting logged as a proper Array, instead of a block of text, in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `............` at the end of the string in `result` is not really part of the string (and is just there to indicate there's more data you haven't posted) then the code you've posted already works correctly (as demonstrated below):

```js
const request = "[[\"0\",\"MahaShivRatri\"],[\"0\",\"A Night with the Divine\"],[\"0\",\"Attend In-Person\"],[\"0\",\"11 March 2021\"],[\"0\",\"6 PM to 6 AM IST\"],[\"0\",\"Attend Mahashivratri celebrations with Sadhguru in the presence of Adiyogi at the Isha Yoga Center\"]]";
const arr = JSON.parse(request);
console.log(arr[0][1]);
```

Comment: Yes, your snippet is working, but it doesn't work in my Chrome Version 88.0.4324.190 (Official Build) (32-bit). I have tried replacing the keyword **var** in my code with **const**, but it always alerts and logs **undefined**. Can I do this differently, may be by receiving an Object and looping through the object?

Comment: Can you post the full `message` string in your question? I'm guessing that string is not truly json. Also, what do you get if you `alert(arr[0]);`? What about if you `alert(arr);`?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have edited my original post. I have provided all the logged text below the word **Edits**

Comment: Thanks for all the help. There was some other issue somewhere else with my code. In my code, I was calling JSON.stringify on my Array twice, but calling JSON.parse on it just once. I removed one call to JSON.stringify and the variable is now getting logged as a proper Array, instead of a block of text, in the console.